# UML diagrams for Sencha-Touch MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch, uml, sencha-touch-2

I am a student, and I just have developed an application using Sencha Touch, which follows the MVCS architecture.

It includes a lots of java-script model-view-controller and store classes.

Application works fine, but the problem is with its documentation.

**Can you help me with any good example that shows the various UML diagrams (class, activity, use case) and how they are  designed for MVC applications?**

Any tutorial or blog post would also be of help.

The list of classes is huge, and so I am not sure if I should put it here.